# How can I find out if someone modified a row in SQL server in a specific date?

Tags: sql-server

I am just wondering, can I find out if somebody wrote a query and updated a row against specific table in some date?

I tried this :

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM sys.sysobjects 
WHERE NAME = ''

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL,NULL) 
WHERE [Lock Information] LIKE '%TheOutoput%'
```

It does not show me ?

Any suggestions.

Comment: Not without some preparations  (like table tracking triggers, trace flags, server triggers, etc.) **before** the actual update statement was issued.

Comment: `fn_dblog()` shows low-level technical information (way too technical for me, I must admit) about the contents of the database transaction log. From what I can see it offers nothing related to such high-level auditing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

No, row level history/change stamps is not built into SQL Server. You need to add that in the table design. If you want an automatic update date column it would typically be set by a trigger on the table.

There is however a way if you *really* need to find out what happened in a forensics scenario. But that is *only* available if you have the right backup plans. What you can do then is to use the DB transaction log to find when the modification was done. Note that this is not anything an application can or should do runtime.